# How to do autocomplete commands in cli application ( golang )?

Tags: go

I want to do autocomplete my commands when press "TAB" key "\t" and execute command when press "ENTER" key "\r?\n". This code for example:

```
package main
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    command, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
         fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", command)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want bash-like functionality, then it's a lot more complicated than just using a bufio reader.

Check https://github.com/chzyer/readline

Answer (score 0):

According to go complete package [master branch](https://github.com/posener/complete/tree/master)

Make sure to add Go package bin path to ~/.bashrc

```sh
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

tested for go version go1.16.3

```sh
go get -u github.com/posener/complete/v2/gocomplete
COMP_INSTALL=1 gocomplete
source ~/.bashrc
```